# how to install Jenkins pipeline plugin with jenkins-plugin-cli?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I tried to install Jenkins pipeline plugin in container.
I added "pipeline" to the Docker file but during build I got

```
Unable to resolve plugin URL https://updates.jenkins.io/latest/pipeline.hpi, or download plugin pipeline to file: status code: 404, reason phrase: Not Found
```

Actually, Jenkins pipeline plugin does not appear in https://updates.jenkins.io/latest/

There are a lot of pipeline plugins, which of them provide a minimum for defining pipeline script in Jenkins?

Comment: Can you give us your Code or snippet of your Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1):

The Pipeline Plugin has the ID `workflow-aggregator`.

You have to replace `pipeline` to `workflow-aggregator` in your Dockerfile.

May sou can give us more information about your Dockerfile, so I can enlarge my answer.